# How to order a list of objects with matching keys from another list?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I need to sort an existing list of object based on another list of objects (with matching keys), but both lists may or may not contain the same keys and number of items. Example:

```
struct Item 
{
    public string _id;
    public Item(string id) { _id = id; }
}

List<Item> totalItems = new List<Item>()
{
    new Item("foo"), new Item("bar"),
    new Item("baz"), new Item("monkey"),
    new Item("cat"), new Item("apple")
};

List<string> preferredSortOrder = new List<string>()
{
    "monkey",
    "cat",
    "zebra",
    "baz"
};
```

So the output would be:

```
monkey
cat
baz
apple
bar
foo
```

This is because the sort order from preferredSortOrder takes precedence, so monkey, cat, and baz are first in the list because they exist in totalItems. If something in preferredSortOrder list doesn't exist in totalItems, it should be ignored. All remaining items in totalItems should then be ordered alphabetically (as you can see above).

I haven't coded in linq for years and everything I've tried so far hasn't worked.

Edit: Based on Calimero's answer, here is the solution:

```
totalItems = totalItems
.OrderBy(item => item._id)
.OrderBy(item => {
    var i = preferredSortOrder.IndexOf(item._id);
    return i == -1 ? totalItems.Count : i;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Do you have duplicates in expected `totalItems` or in `preferredSortOrder`? if yes then what is expected output? is your `_id` property exposed to the outside world?

Comment: There will be no duplicates in totalItems. Possibly in preferredSortOrder, but that would be just a json config error (which we know can always happen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [List.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=netcore-3.1) method of your reference list as your keySelector function parameter of [Enumerable.OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1) with Linq.

```
totalItems.OrderBy(item => preferredSortOrder.IndexOf(item._id)).ToList();
```

EDIT : This would put the elements that are not in the reference list first (because IndexOf will return -1). But you can easily return a value that is greater than any possible index for this case

```
totalItems.OrderBy(item => 
{ 
   var index = preferredSortOrder.IndexOf(item._id);
   return index == -1 ? totalItems.Count : index
}).ToList();
```

You can make an extension method out of this if you have repeated usage.

EDIT 2 : I didnt pay attention that your _id is private (you didnt specify accessibility and it is default accessibility here). You probably want to have a property that uses it as a backing field, or make it public

Comment: yes, I just noticed that. For now, I just updated my question by making it public. Bad form, but that's not critical to this problem.

Comment: What is this line doing "return index == -1 ? totalItems.Count : index" in OrderBy? I'm trying to sort alphabetically with the remaining items in totalItems if the keys don't exist in preferredSortOrder

Comment: I know I could do this with loops, but that wouldn't be as cool. I'm not sure if I can sort the remaining items without using loops though.

Comment: I explained what it does, it puts the remaining elements at the end. If you want to sort the remaining elements alphabetically, you can add a value to the Count. Also you dont tell if your alphabetical order take case into consideration.

Comment: Case doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by adding a value to Count. Count is a readonly member.

Comment: Anyhow, after your solution, I just sorted alphabetically first, then ran your example.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a second string field to struct Item, call it 'sortOrder'.
2. Create a class or struct for 'preferredSortOrder', add a second string field ('sortOrder') that indicates the sort order. Use numbers as they will sort ahead of alpha.
3. Do a first pass through 'totalItems', do a lookup on 'preferredSortOrder', copy the sortOrder. If the item is not found, copy its string (eg "apple").
4. Sort totalItems on sortOrder. Presto!

Comment: I can't modify the sort order list.

Comment: @u84six You don't need to modify the sort order list.